# Change focus to mega menu

Tags: jquery, keyboard, focus, accessibility, menu

I'm using the [jquery jdiv plugin](http://www.peterhintondesign.co.uk/journal/resources/jdiv-with-multiple-instances/) for mega menus.

How can I use jquery to allow the user to keyboard(tab) to the mega menu(div that shows when a link is hovered or focused)?

After the mega menu loses focus, I would like the focus to return to the next navigation bar link.

Basically, I'm just trying to make this all keyboard accessible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tabbing to an element in the page gives it focus, this is from the [jQuery API docs for focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

> An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks on the element.

In your question you suggest that the jQuery jdiv plugin supports opening the div when the particular link gains focus, thus you should just be able to enable that option.

If it does not provide that feature then you could quite easily hook into the plugin.

```
$('.mega-menu-item').focus(function() {
    // Do whatever it is you do to reveal the respective hidden div
    $('.mega-menu-item .hidden-div').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think the problem is that my mega menus that show on hover aren't direct children under the main navigation lists items.  I think this is why they don't receive focus.  I can open the megamenus just fine with the keyboard, I just can't tab to them once they are opened.