# How to make hidden sub menus in WordPress mega-menu focusable

Tags: html, wordpress, accessibility

I have a WordPress mega menu and only the top level menu items seem to be selectable by tabbing to change the focus. All the sub menu items have tabindex="0" on the link but it seems like if the menu items aren't visible on page load, focus skips over them when the parent elements are visible. Any suggestions?

Looks like the same issue this user experienced:
[Change focus to mega menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149507/change-focus-to-mega-menu)

Comment: It looks like they aren't accessible out of the box. You would need to implement focus management so that when someone "tabs" the next item selected is the first menu item. But it is far far more complicated than that as it should work with arrow keys, close when you tab out of it etc. Without a code example (fiddle) to play with all we could do is point you to the relevant guidance and offer very generic advice.

Comment: Does the spacebar or enter key expand your top-level menus? I'm not sure how proficient you are at keyboard-only navigation, but this might help explain how to traverse navigation menus without a mouse: https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/#testing  I agree that without an example, there's only so much assistance that can be offered here.